# Guarantee code execution even on process kill

Tags: c#, .net, process, kill-process

I need to execute a portion of code (the state save) on the process stopping - by itself, by user, by task manager, etc.

Is it possible?

`try {} finally {}`, `AppDomain.ProcessExit`, `IDisposable`, destructor,.. what next to try?

Comment: The whole point of a process being killed ungracefully is that it just stops what it is doing.  I can't really see a way around that.

Comment: What Stephan said; this is exactly why it's a bad idea to kill a process like that... it's *impossible* for the process to recover.

Comment: Still true. Your answer is something else entirely... you can always save state to recover, and there are many ways to do it. But that doesn't change the fact that *a process can not itself do anything when it's been killed*.

Comment: @Stefan: Please post as an answer

Comment: This got off on the wrong premise.  Make your app resilient to somebody tripping over the power cord.  Everything else is then automatically covered as well.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As others have pointed out, there is no way you can execute any code in your application when it is being `Killed` by `Operating System` or `User`. That is why its called `Killing`.

If saving the state is an important part of your application, you should take an approach similar to a database system. Implementing `transaction log`, creating `checkpoints`, etc. That is the closest you can get.

In that case, when your application revives (is re-run after being `killed`), it can check these `transaction logs` for any pending updates or last state changes.

Other than that, it really depends on what you want to do. And also why you came up with this idea? Can we get more details? May be someone here has better alternative.

Comment: It seems that my idea was wrong from the beginning, in both points. I wanted to save state to the same place I read it - App.config. But I can't guarantee neither code execution, not writing to custom section (Exception: The configuration file has been changed by another program). The second problem is much worse. So I think I need to give up on first and rework the second.

Comment: +1 for noting the difference between being `killed` and just being requested to stop.

Comment: Yeah, users can get real cruel (frustrated by some spyware) sometimes. And go on a `killing spree` (trying to find which one is a spyware) using `Task Manager`... :)

Answer (score 11):

The whole point of a process being killed ungracefully is that it just stops what it is doing. I can't really see a way around that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to think about why your program is exiting. If it is because of an error, then you can use try/catch. In unix terms, what goes on when the process manager halts a process is a kill (i.e. sends a SIGKILL signal) which doesnt allow the program to do anything before the process is exited. What many viruses do is have two processes (possibly with shared memory to avoid constant data synchronization), each monitoring the state of the other and when one goes down, the other respawns it. Perhaps a second process could monitor and save the state in a similar way for your case. The other kind of signal though is a SIGTERM. This signal is sent when you tell your computer to restart but there are processes running. The kernel allows the programs to try and quit on their own, but eventually will ask the user if it is okay to kill the program. If you want to handle SIGTERM lookup handling signals. Ultimately the only solution that I know of to the SIGKILL is the two process solution.

Comment: Your answer might somehow help the OP, but saving state somewhere (including in another process) does not do anything to enable a process to *itself* execute code *after* it has been *killed* by the operating system.

Comment: if its a sigterm there is something that that proces can do

Comment: Did you read the question at all? He's asking about a process being *killed*, and mentions `Task Manager` specifically.

Comment: Using a watch-dog seems like a valid idea here. Yes, it is not exactly what OP asked, but it might give him an additional idea. No need to be rude.

Comment: The OP asks about all sorts of ways in which the process can be stopped: "by itself, by user, by task manager, etc." Furthermore, terminology is often confused in CS. For example, you might say that a program gets killed when windows does a restart when it actually gets a sigterm first before it gets actually killed (with sigkill).

Answer (score 3):

I was looking around for a somewhat different reason than what is posted, but I came up with a pretty good solution for myself and it might useful to state here:

NOTE:  To those that know what it is, this is essentially the 'Heartbeat' design pattern.

1) In addition to the code running that will 'die' (ie be killed), add code to this project such that it spawns a thread (or possibly another method?) upon initialization, and all the thread does is run a never-ending while loop (but make sure it sleeps at least a few seconds or even 1 minute between iterations) and in the while loop, record an indicator to indicate your app is 'alive' (ie the 'heartbeat').  I personally recommend setting a value in either the DB, or perhaps a file, that is the current timestamp (ie DateTime.Now)

2) Now that you are recording the 'heartbeat', create another app (ie another process) that does nothing but reads the heartbeat value (ie the current timestamp) and does this in a never-ending while loop.  Once its determined that the heartbeat value is 'bad' (ie maybe if, say, HeartBeatTimestamp + 5 min < DateTime.Now), you can now run your code that you desire to run 'once the process is killed'

Hope this helps :)  Feel free to research the 'Heartbeat' design pattern from other resources to if you want to know more!

Cheers,

Jeff