# Debugging Stopping a Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-services

I'm debugging a windows service in VS2010 with:

```
static void Main()
{
    #if (DEBUG)
        var s1 = new Service1();
        s1.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
    #else
        ServiceBase.Run(new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new Service1() 
            });
    #endif
}
```

This lets me run the service in the debugger. The problem is that on starting, the service opens a WCF channel which seems to tie up a socket after I kill the process by stopping debugging. How do I close this socket when I stop debugging or if the service is stopped. I tried setting breakpoints in the service destructor, and both the `OnStop` and `OnShutdown` methods, but these aren't called.

Comment: Do you use your windows service to self-host a WCF web service, correct?

Comment: I'm hosting a WCF service inside a windows service, yes.

Comment: What kind of binding do you use?

Comment: Also take into account http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479707/guarantee-code-execution-even-on-process-kill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know when you end debugging in Visual Studio, the process is just killed without calls to finalizers and even code located `finally` blocks is not executed.

Comment: What would be the best way to simulate stopping the service. The only way I can see would be to compile, run the service. Then attach the debugger, then stop the service but this is going to get very tedious very quickly trying to debug.

Comment: Agreed. You may also test and debug service's code as a standalone code, without wrapping into the Windows Service. This separation allows you to make sure that the model itself works. I usually create a console application which invokes code used by service, but without service creation.