# WPF app.xaml exit event not working

Tags: c#, wpf, exit, app.xaml

i'm not a pro wpf user so i came here to ask you for help.
I want to update some DB value when the apps exit but nothing happen. here is my app.xaml code:

```
<Application x:Class="pcAdmin.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:pcAdmin"
             Startup="Application_Startup" Exit="Application_Exit"
             >
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

and here is the code behind of the Application_Exit methode:

```
    private void Application_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
            {
//just for verification
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("apps is shutting down");
//updating DB
                conDB = new MySQLConnect(this.connexion_string);
                conDB.connectDB();
                conDB.updateStatus("OFF", IP.mac);
                conDB.disconnect();
                pw.requestStop();
            }
```

NB:- there are no error with all the fonction in the application_exit because they work fine in other part of the program.
   - the apps doesn't have window so i can't use windows_closing or windows_closed event (but tryed it with them and the code work)
I'll appreciate greatly your help. Thank you

Here is the full code of the app.xaml code behind

```
 public partial class App : System.Windows.Application
    {
        private string pData;
        private string pDataPath;
        private NotifyIcon nIcon;
        private string connexion_string;
        private string host;
        private string user;
        private string pwd;
        private string base_sql;
        private InfoPC IP;
        private MySQLConnect conDB;
        private IPChangeDetect ipc;
        private ProcessWorker pw;
        private Programme programme;
        private Service services;
        private List<Svc> sc;
        private AV antivirus;
        private Processor processor;

        private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            this.pData = "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%";
            this.pDataPath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(pData);
            //chargement de l'icon dans la barre de tâche
            nIcon = new NotifyIcon();
            this.nIcon.Icon = new Icon(@"D:\sav Jerrys\pro\getInfo2.0\pcAdmin\pcAdmin\logo.ico");
            nIcon.Visible = true;
            nIcon.BalloonTipText = "Gathering PC info";
            nIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "AEthernam";
            nIcon.ShowBalloonTip(5000);
            //mise à jour de l'application
            getUpdated();
            //obtention des paramètres de connexion à la base de donnée
            recupParam();
            //connexion à la base de donnée et envoi des information pendant le chargement de pcAdmin
            connexion_string = "Server=" + this.host + ";Uid=" + this.user + ";password=" + this.pwd + ";database=" + this.base_sql + ";port=3306";
            this.IP = new InfoPC();
            IP.find_info();
            conDB = new MySQLConnect(connexion_string, IP.mac, IP.ip, IP.domaine, IP.nom);
            conDB.connectDB();
            conDB.sendData();
            //detection du changement d'ip après le chargement du logiciel
            ipc = new IPChangeDetect(conDB);
            ipc.detectIPChange();
            conDB.disconnect();

            //THread for listing process
            pw = new ProcessWorker(connexion_string, IP.mac, pDataPath + @"\AEthernam\proc.bin");
            Thread processThread = new Thread(pw.processWorker);
            processThread.IsBackground = true;
            processThread.Start();
            while (!processThread.IsAlive) ;

            //récupération de la liste des programmes
            recupProg();
            //récupération des services
            recupService();
            //récupération AV
            recupAV();
            //Recup info processeur
            recupProcInfo();
            //TODO:Recup info disque dur physique
            recupPhyDiskInfo();
            //TODO:Recup info partition
            recupLogDiskInfo();
            //TODO:Recup info Mémoire
            recupMemoryInfo();
        }
        private void getUpdated()
        {

            // StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pDataPath + "\\AEthernam\\aethernam.log");
            Version appsVersion = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
            UpdateChecker upChecker = new UpdateChecker(appsVersion.ToString());
            upChecker.checkUpdate();
            //try
            //{
            //    sw.WriteLine(upChecker.getLog);
            //}
            //catch(Exception ex)
            //{
            //    this.log = "erreur ajout log dans le fichier log:\t" + ex.Message;
            //}
        }

        private void recupParam()
        {
            try
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pDataPath + "\\AEthernam\\aethernam.cfg");
                string ligne = sr.ReadLine();
                this.host = ligne;
                ligne = sr.ReadLine();
                this.user = ligne;
                ligne = sr.ReadLine();
                this.pwd = ligne;
                ligne = sr.ReadLine();
                this.base_sql = ligne;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        private void recupProg()
        {
            programme = new Programme();
            List<prog> liste_programe = programme.recupProg();
            conDB = new MySQLConnect(connexion_string, IP.mac);
            conDB.connectDB();
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(pDataPath + @"\AEthernam\prog.bin"))
            {
                List<prog> list_pro = programme.deserialize(pDataPath + @"\AEthernam\prog.bin");
                if (list_pro.Count != liste_programe.Count)
                {
                    //mise à jour de la base des programmes
                    conDB.update_Prog(IP.mac, liste_programe);
                    conDB.disconnect();
                    programme.serialize(list_pro, pDataPath + @"\AEthernam\prog.bin");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                conDB.sendProg(liste_programe);
                conDB.disconnect();
                programme.serialize(liste_programe, pDataPath + @"\AEthernam\prog.bin");
            }
        }
        private void recupService()
        {
            this.services = new Service();
            sc = services.getSvc();
            conDB = new MySQLConnect(connexion_string, IP.mac);
            conDB.connectDB();
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(pDataPath + @"\AEthernam\svc.bin"))
            {
                List<Svc> svcs = services.deserialize(pDataPath + @"\AEthernam\svc.bin");
                if (svcs.Count != sc.Count)
                {
                    //Mise à jour de la base des sevices
                    conDB.updateService(IP.mac, svcs);
                    conDB.disconnect();
                    services.serialize(svcs, pDataPath + @"\AEthernam\svc.bin");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //insertion des services dans la base
                conDB.sendService(sc);
                conDB.disconnect();
                services.serialize(sc, pDataPath + @"\AEthernam\svc.bin");
            }
        }
        private void recupAV()
        {
            List<AV> listAv = new List<AV>();
            FindAv avInstallé = new FindAv();
            ManagementObjectCollection avs = avInstallé.AvInstalled();
            foreach (ManagementObject mo in avs)
            {
                antivirus = new AV();
                antivirus.nom = mo["DisplayName"].ToString();
                antivirus.etat = avInstallé.findState(mo["productState"].ToString());
                listAv.Add(antivirus);
            }
            conDB = new MySQLConnect(connexion_string, IP.mac);
            conDB.connectDB();
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(pDataPath + @"\AEthernam\prog.bin"))
            {
                foreach (AV av in listAv)
                {
                    conDB.sendAV(av);
                    conDB.disconnect();

                }

            }
            else
            {
                conDB.updateAV(IP.mac, listAv);
                conDB.disconnect();
            }
        }
        private void recupMemoryInfo()
        {
            List<Ram> liste_ram = new List<Ram>();
            liste_ram = new RamInfo().getRams();
            conDB = new MySQLConnect(connexion_string, IP.mac);
            conDB.connectDB();
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(pDataPath + @"\AEthernam\prog.bin"))
            {
                conDB.sendRam(liste_ram);
                conDB.disconnect();
            }
            else
            {
                conDB.updateRam(IP.mac, liste_ram);
                conDB.disconnect();
            }
        }
        private void recupPhyDiskInfo()
        {
            List<DisquePhysique> liste_pdisk = new List<DisquePhysique>();
            liste_pdisk = new PhysicalDiskInfo().getPDisk();
            conDB = new MySQLConnect(connexion_string, IP.mac);
            conDB.connectDB();
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(pDataPath + @"\AEthernam\prog.bin"))
            {
                conDB.sendPhydisque(liste_pdisk);
                conDB.disconnect();
            }
            else
            {
                conDB.updatePhydisque(IP.mac, liste_pdisk);
                conDB.disconnect();
            }
        }
        private void recupLogDiskInfo()
        {
            List<LogicalDisk> liste_ldisk = new List<LogicalDisk>();
            liste_ldisk = new LogicalDiskInfo().getPartition();
            conDB = new MySQLConnect(connexion_string, IP.mac);
            conDB.connectDB();
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(pDataPath + @"\AEthernam\prog.bin"))
            {
                conDB.sendLdisque(liste_ldisk);
                conDB.disconnect();
            }
            else
            {
                conDB.updateLdisque(IP.mac, liste_ldisk);
                conDB.disconnect();
            }
        }
        private void recupProcInfo()
        {
            processor = new Processor();
            ProcessorInfo pInfo = new ProcessorInfo();
            processor = pInfo.getInfo();
            conDB = new MySQLConnect(connexion_string, IP.mac);
            conDB.connectDB();
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(pDataPath + @"\AEthernam\prog.bin"))
            {
                conDB.sendProcessor(processor);
                conDB.disconnect();
            }
            else
            {
                conDB.updateProcessor(IP.mac, processor);
                conDB.disconnect();
            }
        }

        private void Application_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("apps is shutting down");
            conDB = new MySQLConnect(this.connexion_string);
            conDB.connectDB();
            conDB.updateStatus("OFF", IP.mac);
            conDB.disconnect();
            pw.requestStop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What type of app is this if you don't have window?

Comment: Change System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show() to MessageBox.SHow(), and why are you using the Windows.Forms inside a WPF application?

Comment: it's check and provide information for network monitoring so the user don't need to interact with it so i've disabled any UI based related the messabox is only for verification purpose.

Comment: Can you please specify what "pw" is? Be more specific please

Comment: B.Hulshof the windows.forms is there only cause i've needed a way to verify if the code inside the application_exit is executed but on the final release it will be removed.

Comment: B.Huslhof the pw is an instance of a thread that works countinuously till the program shutdown. pw.requestStop() is there to make the thread stop

Comment: But is your Application_Exit method even called? Have you placed a break point there?

Comment: @3615 since the messabebox don't show i don't think that the methode is called and that's where my problem is why it isn't called?

Comment: Ok, but how do you close your application? You are doing it programmatically, since it has no UI? Could you show that code?

Comment: Please add more detail to the code in your question, thank you.

Comment: the application is supposed to run countinuously so to stop the application the only way is to end it's process in the taskmanager.

Comment: Ok i'll add the full code now just a sec i'm finding a way on how to put it clearly here

Comment: And since you have no window you need to exit the app programatically, like this: Application.Current.Shutdown();

Comment: I think the reason event is not fired is that you are not closing the application gracefully, but killing the process.

Comment: Ok i've updated the question so that anyone can see some part of the code the application startup works fine. @B.Hulshof where should i put this shutdown instruction then?

Comment: You would need some UI or a tray icon at least, that will allow you closing the application gracefully on some button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  have a feeling the problem is related to the thread you have. If it's a [foreground thread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it is not allowing the application to exit until it's running. And since you are trying to stop it in the Exit_Application method, that's never happening. 
Try setting somewhere where you are creating the thread.

```
pw.IsBackground = true;
```

If you are using new Thread() to create it, it always default's to foreground thread.

UPDATE:

Since the application is closing from the Task Manager, the process is simply killed by windows and there is no way to execute some code before it closes. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4479816/5246145) for a workaround, involving DB.
Or you would need some UI or a tray icon at least, that will allow you closing the application gracefully on some button click.
To gracefully close the application you can use previously suggested:

```
Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

Comment: thank you for your answer,i've modified my code as you suggested but didn't work. here is a sample code of the thread that's been runing

Comment: //THread for listing process
            pw = new ProcessWorker(connexion_string, IP.mac, pDataPath + @"\AEthernam\proc.bin");
            Thread processThread = new Thread(pw.processWorker);
            processThread.IsBackground = true;
            processThread.Start();
            while (!processThread.IsAlive) ;

Comment: the problem is that i don't need to close the apps, i need to send data to a db saying that the user has stoped the apps :) in this case only by killing it's process

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    //your current code
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

this should trigger the Exit method of your application and run the code within the application_exit();

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answer and help, I'll put @3615 answer as an acceptable solution for me. I'll gona find some way to see if user killed process then update my DB accordingly