# Possible to run a function before "rudely" interrupting a program?

Tags: c#

So I've created a program which can't be seen when it's running unless you look for the process in the task manager because of these three lines:

```
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
this.Hide();
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

I'd like the program to run a function when it's getting shutdown but i don't know if this is possible. If I had a form, i could use the Form.Closed() event handler but in this case, you'd have to close the program by terminating the process explicitly which means Form.Closed() isn't being called. Since the program connects to a server, i'd like it to disconnect from that server when the program is terminated. Is it possible though when there's no command line or GUI?

Regards,
 Jones

Comment: this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479707/guarantee-code-execution-even-on-process-kill

Comment: Your program looks more like a service than a regular program, did you thought on creating it as a service? In this way you can control the start/stop of the service as it's intended, no need to kill it and you can do operations on the Start and Stop events of the service controller.

Comment: i didnt think of that, im gonna look it into it :)